# Redirecionar para outra página ao dar erro no cadastro!

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu tenho um sistema de cadastro, que não permite que o usuário cadastre com um email já cadastrado, porém quando eu faço o cadastro com um email já existente, ele não redireciona o usuário para a página de cadastro. Eu usei a tag `header='Location(cadastro.php?erro=1)'`.

Tem alguma outra tag que possa ser usada? Ou oque poderia estar errado pra ele não estar redirecionando?

Aqui está o código php que tenta fazer o cadastro no banco:

```
 <?php
    session_start();    
    require_once('conecta.php');

    // RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
    $nome   = $_POST ["nome"];
    $data   = $_POST ["data"];
    $email  = $_POST ["email"];
    $email2 = $_POST ["email2"];
    $senha  = $_POST ["senha"]; 


    $arq = $_FILES['foto']['name'];

    $arq = $_FILES['foto']['name'];

    $arq = str_replace(" ", "_", $arq);
    $arq = str_replace("ç", "c", $arq);

    if (file_exists("imagens/".$arq)) {
        $a = 1;

        while (file_exists("imagens/[".$a."]".$arq)) {
            $a++;
        }

        $arq = "[".$a."]".$arq;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], 'imagens/'.$arq)) {
        $objDb = new db();
        $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
        $sql = "insert into voluntarios (nome, data, email, email2, senha,  foto) values ('$nome', '$data', '$email', '$senha', '".$arq."')";
        if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){


            echo '<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar-transparente">
              <div class="container">
                <!-- Header -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <!-- botao toggle -->
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao">
                    <span class="sr-only">Alternar navegação</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>

                  <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
                    <span><img src="imagens/logoviladobem.png" width="80px"></span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <!-- navbar -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barra-navegacao">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li class="divisor" role="separator"></li>
                    <li><a href="facaparte.php">Faça Parte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="entrar.php">Entrar</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="capa">
              <div class="texto-capa">
                <h1>Parabéns por ter tido essa inciativa, seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!</h1>
                <h3>Um e-mail foi enviado para o e-mail cadastrado com algumas informações importantes.</h3>
              </div>
            </div>';
        } else {
            header('Location: cadastro.php?erro=1');
        }

    } else {
        header('Location: cadastro.php?erro=1');
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: Ele está caindo no else? pois o comando header está certinho.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Está caindo sim, eu coloquei um echo pra verificar se estava caindo, e ele executou normalmente

Answer (score -1):

Definir outro cabeçalho sozinho não é suficiente para redirecionar. Tente assim:

else {
   header('Location: cadastro.php?erro=1');
   exit();
}

Comment: Mesmo assim ele não redireciona!